# Using 'git branch -D. prevented updates when branch with same name was recreated

Tags: git

I have a main branch named *prod*.  Previously as will be explained below I had deleted a remote branch on *prod* which had been previously pushed:

```
git branch -D CPR1793prod
```

Note that this deleted both the local and remote branches.
I then proceeded to work with branch *prod*:

```
git checkout prod
Switched to branch prod
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/prod'.
```

*prod* contains a file errors_en.json that I want to update, so I create a branch:

```
git checkout -b CPR1793prod
Switched to a new branch 'CPR1793prod'
```

I moved the updated file into this directory and did an *add* and *commit*

```
git add .
git commit .
[CPR1793prod de136b2] Correct spelling as noted in CPR-1699 and -1793
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)
```

And then of course I attempted to push the updates with the following results:

```
git push origin CPR1793prod
To https://<pathname obfuscated>/scm/opscfg/errors.git
 ! [rejected]        CPR1793prod -> CPR1793prod (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://p-bitbucket.<obfuscated>.com/scm/opscfg/errors.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Although the message says that the current branch (CPR1793prod) is behind its remote counterpart, it is not.  We tried this many times looking at the fie contents, doing a pull right after checking out *prod*, looking in bitbucket after doing

```
git branch -D CPR1793prod
```

to ensure that the remote branch was indeed "deleted", and doing a

```
git branch
```

to ensure the local branch was not present (was "deleted").

The problem was resolved when I changed the name of the branch (from 'CPR1793prod' to '1793prod'). What this indicated to me was that the command:

```
git branch -D <branch name>
```

must not have worked properly and somehow left behind some detritus that I cannot not detect to make at least the *git push* command not work properly.

Note that I did this set of commands to several other repositories with no problems.

- Has anyone seen this problem before?
- Does anyone see something I did wrong (which would surprise me since 
  when I changed the branch name that had been deleted it worked fine.)
- Does anyone have a suggestion on where the problem might come from, and how to fix it?

Comment: "Note that this deleted both the local and remote branches", are you sure about that? It may have deleted the local branch and the *remote **tracking** branch*, but it did not delete the branch **on the remote**.

Comment: You have 3 branches involved when you are doing push and pull. You have the local branch (A), maintained by git checkout and commit and so on. You have the branch **on the remote** (3) which lives in another repository entirely. And then you have the remote **tracking** branch (2), which tracks where the branch is on the remote. This branch lives locally and is named `remote/branch-name`. You deleted the two local branches (1 and 2), you did not delete the branch on the remote (3), so git didn't want you to push to that branch because they were out of sync.

Comment: After I did the 'git branch -D CPR1793prod' I did a 'git branch' and did not see it listed and I looked in bitbucket and the branch did not exist.  So from at least that perspective both the local and remote branches appeared to be deleted

Comment: How did you configure git to delete the branch on the remote using `git branch -D`?

Comment: Your comment about the 3 branches may be correct.  However, I performed this process with other branches and it id work.  However, I have a question for you:  if the tracking branch was not deleted in this case, how should I have deleted it?

Comment: You can delete a branch on the remote using `git push <remote-name> -d <branch-name>`, so most likely `git push origin -d CPR1793prod`. You thus "push a delete", you don't push other commits and such.

Comment: I just found that.  I think that the site that showed the 'git branch -D <branch>' deleting the remote branch was in error (-D is actually short for  --delete --force which I would have known had I done a 'git help branch' :-( ).  I can't explain the behavior I saw or why this process sometimes worked.  Since my 'git branch -D <branch>' did delete the local branch - it is missing from the .git/branches directory - the push actually did correctly report that the current branch was behind the remote branch since the current branch didn't exist.

Comment: It would be nice if 'git push' correctly reported that the local branch didn't exist (if I understand things correctly).  And for the record I have no idea how the remote branch was deleted.  Even though 2 of us looked I question whether it really was deleted.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that [`git branch -D ...`] deleted both the local and remote branches ...

No, it didn't.

It's usually inappropriate to use your own `git branch` command to remove your own (local) remote-tracking names, such as `refs/remotes/origin/CPR1793prod`, but to do that, you would have to run a second `git branch -d` or `git branch -D` command:

```
git branch -D -r origin/CPR1793prod
```

for instance.  (The reason it's not really appropriate is that your Git is trying to keep track of *their* Git's branches.  Deleting this locally has no real effect: if they still have a `CPR1793prod`, your next `git fetch origin` will just bring back your `origin/CPR1793prod`.)

(To list your own ordinary branch names, use `git branch`.  To list your remote-tracking names, use `git branch -r`.  To list both at the same time, use `git branch -a`.  Try `git branch -r` and `git branch -a` now and observe the odd difference in which one of them prints names like `origin/master` and the other prints names like `remotes/origin/master`.  Why?  Who knows.  The *full* name is `refs/remotes/origin/master`; it's allowable to strip off the `refs/` or the `refs/remotes/` part; and one of the two commands strips just `refs/`, and the other strips `refs/remotes/`.)

To ask the *other Git* to delete *its own* `CPR1793prod`, use `git push`, either with `--delete` or with the deletion refspec syntax:

```
git push origin --delete CPR1793prod
```

or:

```
git push origin :CPR1793prod
```

both of which send to the Git over at `origin` a request of the form: *Please delete your own `CPR1793prod` branch.*  If (a) this works—the remote is allowed to deny this request, in which case you need to see why it did that—and (b) you follow this up with:

```
git fetch origin --prune
```

your Git will automatically delete your `refs/remotes/origin/CPR1793prod` remote-tracking name.

(I like to set `fetch.prune` to `true` in my `--global` Git configuration, so that every `git fetch` acts like a `git fetch --prune`.  There's no need to have my own Git repositories hang on to remote-tracking names for names that were deleted.  I think this should be the default, and you should have to configure `fetch.prune` to `false` to *dis*able this behavior, but that would not be backwards-compatible.)

Comment: Correct.  The site (which I'm not going to go back and find) that incorrectly reported the difference between the -d and -D options was incorrect as noted above on the comments.  I gave both you and  Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen an upvote.  I also like you suggestion on fetch.  Excellent response.